# Bootstrap Modal doesn't appear when clicked, instead effects the <body> tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following Html on my page for displaying a modal, pretty basic right?
this is located at the bottom of my page.

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myStupidModal">Launch Modal</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="myStupidModal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
</div>
```

When I click the "Launch Modal" my page flickers and my scroll bar dis-appears, yet when I click "Launch Modal" again the page flickers and my scroll bar appears again, so I decided to check out firebug to see if any errors have been raised, error count = 0

Then I look at my HTML and this is what I see when clicking on "Launch Modal"

Before clicking

[image]

After is is clicked, you can see styles being assigned to the  tag of the Html document? huh? how? why?

[image]

How is this happening? what is wrong with the modal? I've never experienced this before when working with bootstrap modals.

Comment: have a look to this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava thanks for that, I copied one of the examples and I can see the model appear, bur when I click on the "Launch Modal" it applies     class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px to the body tag of my HTML page, which results in the page shifting, and then when I close the model the page shifts back to its starting position

Comment: can you http://jsfiddle.net it??

Comment: `class="modal hide"` is wrong for Bootstrap v3. Should just be `class="modal"`.

Comment: I am having this same exact issue too. Can anyone please help??